# Simple java rand() syntax

Tags: java, random

I got a really simple question today.

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(50)
```

Does this code return numbers from 0 to 49 or from 0 to 50(**including** 50)

And how abaut this one?

```
Random r = new Random();
10 + r.nextInt(50)
```

From 10 to 60(**including** 60)?

Comment: When you looked at the documentation for `Random#nextInt()`, what did you find?

Comment: There is no syntax question here, just a trivial question about semantics that is already answered by the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered directly in [the docs for `nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) (emphasis added):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (**exclusive**)

The argument is strictly greater than the maximum integer that will be returned.

```
r.nextInt(50)
```

might return 0 and might return 49, but won't return 50. Similarly,

```
10 + r.nextInt(50)
```

might be 59, but will never be 60.

Answer (score 3):

> > nextInt(int n)- Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29), it's `0..n` exclusive.

> > the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive) from this random number generator's sequence

So, if you want `10..60` inclusive, use the following code:

```
10+r.nextInt(51);
```